# The move vnode is compacted at the same time, but the move vnode is stuck for a long time. What's going on?

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

The move vnode is compacted at the same time, but the move vnode is stuck for a long time. What's going on?

1. I move vnode to another node;

   ```
   benchmark ❯ move vnode 6 to node  2001;
   ```
2. compact vnode 6 as same time;

   ```
   public ❯ compact vnode 6;
   Query took 1.785 seconds.
   ```

It took a long time to move the vnode without success. the log as follow:

```
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"020003","error_message":"request timed out"}
```

Way timeout? Has anyone encountered this problem?